# Pause execution of a loop in main method till all Threads finish Java 1.5

Tags: java, multithreading, java-5

I am reading multiple arguments from command line using Java 1.5 . The arguments are names of flat files. I loop thru the arguments in the main method and call a method which in turn creates a bunch of threads to process the file. I need to pause the loop till all threads processing the first argument complete and then move on to create threads for the second argument. How can I queue the arguments or pause the loop execution in my main method till all threads processing current argument complete?

Answer (score 0):

Use Threadpools and an Executor. Take a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package.

```
for(String argument:args){
  //you said you want multiple threads to work on a single argument.
  //create callables instead and use a ThreadPool
  List<Callable<YourResult>> lstCallables = createCallablesFor(argument);
  List<Future<YourResult>> futures = Executors.newCachedThreadPool().invokeAll(lstCallables);
  for(Future<YourResult> future:futures){
    //this get() waits until the thread behind the current future is done.
    // it also returns whatever your callable might return.
    future.get(); 
  }
  // at this point, all the threads working on the current argument are finished
  // and the next loop iteration works on the next argument
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are looking for something like [cyclic barriers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the thread job inside the loop for one argument so that after one job is finished next loop is started and next thread job for next argument is started. And further you can work in your thread job where you defined that.

Example: this is just a snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    t[i] = new RunDemo();
    String[] serverList = srv[i].split(",");
    String logName = filename + "_" + serverList[0] + "_log";
    String sql = "INSERT INTO .....(any query)";
    t[i].setStr("sqlplus -L " + username[i] + "/" + password[i] + "@"
                + serverList[1] + ":" + serverList[2] + "/" + serverList[3]
                + " @" + filename1);
    t[i].setLogName(logName);
    t[i].setDirectory(dir);
    try{
        conn.UpdateQuery(sql);
        log.info("Inserted into the table data with query " + sql);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        log.info("The data can't be inserted into table with " + e.getMessage() + " sql query " + sql);
    }
    new Thread(t[i]).start();
}
```

Here in every loop new thread with different serverList is created and started.

Now the job definition is given below:

```
public void run() {
    JShell jshell = new JShell();
    try {
        log.info("Command is: " + this.str + " log name: " + this.LogName + " in directory: " + this.directory);
        jshell.executeCommand(this.str, this.LogName, this.directory);
        log.info("Executed command successfully");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        log.info("Error at executing command with error stack: ");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    DBConnection conn1 = new DBConnection();
    String sql = "UPDATE patcheventlog SET ENDTIME=SYSDATE WHERE LOGFILE='" + this.directory + this.LogName + "'";
    try {
        //conn1.callConnection("192.168.8.81", "d2he");

        conn1.callConnection(ip, sid);

        conn1.UpdateQuery(sql);
        conn1.disposeConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(this.LogName);
}
```

So this is how you work with the threads inside the loop. You don't need to pause your loop.

Hope that helps.